# how to use 'vor = ago' correctly in sentences

Tags: english-to-german, preposition

I would like to know how I can ask a question with *vor = ago* correctly in the following sentences:

> What is in my calendar from three day ago?
> Was in meinem Kalender von vor drei Tagen steht?

or

> What did I have in my calendar three day ago?
> Was hatte ich vor drei Tagen in meinem Kalender?

In particular I would like to know whether I need to keep the preposition *from* like in the first sentence. The example sentences are to check the activities I did three days ago based on what I wrote in my calendar.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are possible (read grammatically) correct, but in my opinion a little awkward. Nevertheless you'd be understood. I would phrase it this way

> Ich muss mal in meinem Kalender schauen,  ...
> ... was ich vor 3 Tagen gemacht hatte.
> ... welche Termine ich vor 3 Tagen hatte.
> ... wo ich vor 3 Tagen war.
> ... wohin ich vor 3 Tagen gefahren war.
> ... mit wem ich vor 3 Tagen verabredet war.

Regarding your sentences:

> was in meinem Kalender von vor drei Tagen steht

This kind of implies that you use a new calendar for each day. Which is what makes it awkward, because usually people use just one calendar for the entire year.

> Was hatte ich vor drei Tagen in meinem Kalender?

This means that it was in your calendar 3 days ago (but you erased it after that).

Comment: ... was ich vor 3 Tagen gemacht *habe*? ...

Comment: "Both sentences are possible (read grammatically) correct" - I have some severe doubts "Was in meinem Kalender von vor drei Tagen steht?" can be labeled grammatically correct, at least if it is supposed to be a full sentence, rather than a partial repetition of a previous statement for confirmation.

Comment: Also, I disagree about the "but you erased it after that" claim. I think it is perfectly possible to ask "Was hatte ich vor drei Tagen in meinem Kalender?", where the past tense does *not* indicate the calendar has physically changed in the meantime, just that my focus with respect to the calendar has shifted.

Comment: Note the difference between "was ich hatte ich vor drei Tagen in meinem Kalender" and "Was hatte ich in meinem Kalender von vor drei Tagen"